# How to retrieve lost tex documents from bak files?

Tags: scientific-workplace

a friend of mine using an old version of scientific workplace software lost his `tex` file , i was able to recover files but with the extension `bak` so i'm wondering how to get back the `tex` files from those `bak` files.

Comment: isn't it simply a copy, so rename it back to tex ?

Comment: ok, i'll try that i hope it works , thanks a lot 
i'll let you update sir , thanks a lot